# Testing the asset pipeline with Capybara

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capybara, asset-pipeline

I want to do simple request specs in my Rails 3.1 application with Capybara. The standard cases all work as expected, but when I want to test CSS generated by the asset pipeline, I receive the following error:

```
Failure/Error: visit '/assets/main.css'
ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches [GET] "/assets/main.css"
```

I think the problem is that the test environment does not provide a complete server and so also no Sprockets middleware delivering the assets.
Is there a solution to this problem?

**EDIT: Now possible!**
We updated to Rails 3.2.12 and Capybara 2.0.2, now the assets are also available in the feature specs.

Comment: i don't think so. as far as i know it spawns up a new server on a specific test port (see config Capybara.server_port)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Phusion guys blogged about a possibility to [render an asset to a string](http://blog.phusion.nl/2011/08/14/rendering-rails-3-1-assets-to-string/):

```
MyApp::Application.assets.find_asset('main.css').body
```

You can also use this in tests. The solution is not ideal and/since Capybara isn't involved anymore, but it helps in my specific case to validate CSS. Better approaches are welcome!